# Не находит модуль при развертывании на Heroku

Tags: node.js, vue.js, heroku, vue-router

При попытке развернуть приложение на Heroku, появляется ошибка, что модуль не найден.

```
   Hash: ae62203337abd2a15df9
   Version: webpack 3.10.0
   Time: 5889ms
   Asset     Size  Chunks             Chunk Names
   build.js   122 kB       0  [emitted]  main
   build.js.map   996 kB       0  [emitted]  main
   build.js.gz  43.1 kB          [emitted]

   ERROR in ./src/router/index.js
   Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../components/index.vue' in '/tmp/build_98234cb35db9591e3ab6b0a8d6c11fd1/src/router'
   @ ./src/router/index.js 15:13-47
   @ ./src/app.js
   @ multi ./src/app.js

   ERROR in ./src/router/index.js
   Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../components/vueJS.vue' in '/tmp/build_98234cb35db9591e3ab6b0a8d6c11fd1/src/router'
   @ ./src/router/index.js 19:13-47
   @ ./src/app.js
   @ multi ./src/app.js
   npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
```

Хотя при этом на локальной машине все собирается и запускается без проблем.
Переменные конфигурации на Heroku выглядят следующим образом:

```
  NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error
  NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false
  NODE_VERBOSE=false
  NODE_ENV=production
  NODE_MODULES_CACHE=false
```

Comment: Вы все модули импортируете/экспортируете корректно? В конфиге вебпака правильно указали пути для сборки? Часто такая ошибка возникает именно из-за неправильно прописанных путей.